# Showing that a map is conformal

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A\colon\,\mathbb R^2 →\mathbb R^2$ be a linear map, and suppose there exists $c > 0$ such that $\langle Av, Aw\rangle = c \langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v, w ∈ \mathbb R^2$

Show that $A$ preserves the angles between vectors.

My attempt:

I have to show that $A$ is conformal.

Since $A$ is a linear map, we can write $Av = A(v.1) = v.A(1) = v$ and $Aw = A(w.1) = w.A(1) = w$.

And so, I would have $\langle Av,Aw\rangle = \langle v,w\rangle = c\langle v,w\rangle$.

Hence $\langle v,w\rangle = c\langle v,w\rangle$, so the angle between $v$ and $w$ hasn't changed. The inner product has just been multiplied by a constant $c$ which has dilated and rotated $\langle v,w\rangle$.

Thus $A$ is conformal.

Is my attempt correct? Any other solutions to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No – a linear map $A$ takes *vectors into vectors* – expression $A(1)$ is not defined, because 1 is not a vector.

The angle between two vectors $v, w$ can be calculated using its cosine

$$\cos\angle(v,w) = \frac{\langle v, w\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle \langle w, w\rangle }}$$

Just express $\cos\angle(Av,Aw)$
using the above definition and the property of map $A$.

Comment: I calculated cos$(Av,Aw)$ as u told me to, and I got that it's equal to cos$(v,w)$. So this means that the angle $(Av, Aw)$ = angle $(v, w) $. And thus $A$ is conformal?

Comment: Exactly! As a small remark – some people measure the angles in the directed way and they call our "conformal" maps "isogonal", reserving word "conformal" for a bit stronger property.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much!